# Python - 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

Tags: python, numpy

So i manually entered a `197x197` matrix (oops) into Python and now I want to raise it to a power. But, when I use Matrix_powers, the above error comes up..

I entered the matrix like this :

```
A = numpy.array([
               [ ...... ]
               ])
```

I used `len(A[i])` for every `i` to see the number of elements in each row, and all of them say `197`. However, when I use `numpy.shape`, the dimensions are printed as `(197, )` so I really don't know how this is possible.

Comment: I think it is better to add the code in order to help you.

Comment: also, what is the output of A.shape?

Comment: hm... this is very curious.  Did you enter your matrix like:
```A = numpy.array([
               [ 1, 2, 3, ..., 197 ],
               [ 1, 2, 3, ..., 197],
               .... ... ...
               [ 1, 2, 3, ..., 197]
               ])
```
?

Comment: What's the `dtype`?  A 1d object dtype array is a pretty good indication that you made a mistake in the manual entry, and one or more rows has a different length.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this? (elaborating Kevin's comment)

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[i for i in range(1,198)] for j in range(1,198)])
A
A.shape
```

will produce

```
array([[  1,   2,   3, ..., 195, 196, 197],
       [  1,   2,   3, ..., 195, 196, 197],
       [  1,   2,   3, ..., 195, 196, 197],
       ...,
       [  1,   2,   3, ..., 195, 196, 197],
       [  1,   2,   3, ..., 195, 196, 197],
       [  1,   2,   3, ..., 195, 196, 197]])
(197, 197)
```